# Defining length of CHAR type in Mysql

Tags: mysql, types

Consider the two String types in MySQL

**1.Char[LENGTH]**

**2.Varchar[LENGTH]**

Question:Defining the **LENGTH** field is necessary For which type Varchar  or Char ?

According to My opinion It is Char but In one tutorial it is written that you must define Length for Varchar while there is no such requirement for Char type.

**CHAR(M)** - A fixed-length string between 1 and 255 characters in length (for example

CHAR(5)), right-padded with spaces to the specified length when stored. Defining a length

is not required, but the default is 1.

**VARCHAR(M)** - A variable-length string between 1 and 255 characters in length; for

example VARCHAR(25). You must define a length when creating a VARCHAR field.

Link: www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-data-types.htm

Is the thing Written in Tutorial Right?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm clear with what you are looking for .

Take a look at this.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (column1 VARCHAR(20), column2 CHAR);

insert into mytable values('stackoverflow','v');
select * from mytable;
```

If you don't specify the length for char datatype it will take 1 as default.

Now if you try to `insert string in column2` more than length 1 it will raise an error.

Summary : Varchar datatype need length otherwise it will raise an error where in char datatype if you don't specify the length it will take 1 as default.